# ADD Html URL Parameters with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters

Just want a variable parameter in an html url like this:

`mywebpage.com/something.html?width=(Parameter1)&height=(Parameter2)`

But in the content of that webpage i want to add this:

`<script>fid="example"; width=(Parameter1); height=(Parameter2);</script>`

How can i do it using only javascript and Html

Answer (score 0):

Here is code suggested from similar question ([How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter))

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();
```

Comment: I want something like this http://www.redzer.tv/canal1.php?width=350&height=200 but in html, look at that url when you change the width value in the url, it changes the width of the videostream content, Is there a way to do that in HTML and javascript?

Answer (score -1):

So long the list of variables is somewhat fixed and small in quantity, keep it simple.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="some-link-id>Click me!</a>
```

JS:

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

var link  = document.getElementById('some-link-id');
var url   = "http://mywebpage.com/page.html?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
link.href = url;
```

Or to update the URL of the page you are on, simply set `window.location.href`

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

var url = "http://mywebpage.com/page.html?width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: I want something like this http://www.redzer.tv/canal1.php?width=350&height=200 but in html, look at that url when you change the width value in the url, it changes the width of the videostream content, Is there a way to do that in HTML and javascript?

Comment: Yes there is. It is my answer. That's why it has `HTML` and `JS` in it. So I don't understand your question...

Comment: But it doesnt work check out that webpage it contains a videostream, it can not change with your method

Comment: You want to change the URL of the page you are on? Oh, that was totally not clear... See my edit.

Comment: Yes look how it changes, compare:
http://www.redzer.tv/canal1.php?width=350&height=200
 and
http://www.redzer.tv/canal1.php?width=720&height=480
Thats made with php but i wanna do that with html and javascript

Comment: I cannot figure out what you want here. You will need to be much more specific.

Comment: look http://www.pirlotves.com/canal-1.php there says "copy this code into your website so you can get the video in the size you want" that code includes an iframe to a php webpage where the video is stored, i want to do that but in html and javascript, if you help me i can offer you some money